# CSS issue - I have to remove float:left - Any ideas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to remove the float: left from:

```
.Container70 {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Otherwise my footer is at the middle of the page if the content is larger then the whole page.

Here my whole CSS Code:

```
<head>
<body>
<div id="container-wrapper">
<form id="topForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/gixxshare/Testewr" method="post" name="topForm">
<div id="layout-topbar-cover-custom">
<div id="layout-portlets-cover-custom">
<div class="Responsive100 Container70">
<div class="ContainerIndent">
<div class="Card ShadowEffect HeiAutoOnMobile">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="layout-footer">Test</div>
</div>


#container-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

@media ( min-width : 960px) {
    #layout-topbar-cover-custom {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0 3rem;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }
}

@media ( max-width : 960px) {
    #layout-topbar-cover-custom {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }
}

#layout-portlets-cover-custom {
    display: block;
    padding: 70px 10px 30px 0.1%;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}

#layout-footer {
    background: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}


.Container70 {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
.Responsive100 {
}

.ContainerIndent {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#layout-portlets-cover::before, #layout-portlets-cover::after, .Card::before, .Card::after {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#layout-portlets-cover::after, .Card::after {
    clear: both;
}
#layout-portlets-cover::before, #layout-portlets-cover::after, .Card::before, .Card::after {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.ShadowEffect {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(43, 59, 93, 0.4);
}
.Card {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #546e7a;
    display: block;
    font-family: "roboto_condensedregular";
    padding: 10px;
}
.HeiAutoOnMobile {
}
```

I don´t want to remove float: left from Container because this is the class from bootstrap this means I have to adjust all container.
How can I solve this? Any ideas?

Comment: Please post all your CSS code.

Comment: I don't see any element with class Container70 in your html - can you clarify?

Comment: I think you are missing a closing </div>